# How to disable Enter key autocomplete for Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

For the normal editor windows in Visual Studio Code I can disable `Enter` key auto completion using the following workspace setting:

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"`

However this does not disable the `Enter` key auto completion for Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code. Which workspace setting should I use for that?

I tried:

`"jupyter.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"`

but that didn't work.

As an example I type:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then press `Enter`

which causes Visual Studio code to change this to:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot`

which is really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not currently supported in the notebook editor. The notebook editor does not read all of editor settings for VS code at the moment.

You can log this as a bug on the python extension here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues